# How do I make an non-toxic, low cost DIY cleaning solution for laminate floors?

Tags: kitchens, cleaning, laminate-floor

My kitchen's laminate floors quickly become dirty from food and dog bowl spills. Instead of spending a fortune on potentially toxic cleaning solutions, I'd like to make my own cleaning solution that is safe, cheap, and leaves no residue. I've heard mixed reviews on vinegar and dishsoap solutions, but I'd imagine they leave a residue, and I don't think soap is necessarily great for pets and kids (or humans) to ingest. Does anyone have a recipe they have found works for laminate floors?

Comment: Soap can leave a film of soap.  Vinegar is a good cleaner, cheap, and evaporates without leaving traces of itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pure water is not good for dissolving greasy residue. I use warm water with a small amount of dish washing detergent in it to mop the ceramic tile in the kitchen and throughout the house. I do not do a second mopping of the floor with water. The small residue of detergent left on the floor presents absolutely no risk. I figure if this detergent is safe for dishes (of course I do rinse the dishes) it is safe for the floor.

Answer (score 1):

2 parts hydrogen, one part oxygen.

Comment: H2O, the universal solvent. No residue, non-toxic, fast drying, odorless, non-staining, and delicious mixed with aged CH3CH2OH!